# MongoDB MMS automation agent for windows

Tags: mongodb-mms

I am looking into setting up MMS Automation agent but found out that there is no download for windows. Is it not available for windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, the MMS automation agent is not available on Windows yet. A windows version is on the roadmap for the future (nothing concrete at the time of writing this), but for now if you want to use the automation agent you need to be running on [Linux](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/tutorial/nav/install-automation-agent/) or [Mac OS X](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/tutorial/install-automation-agent-on-osx/).

Comment: I have installed automation agent on Ubuntu. but I am not sure about the next step to connect mms to that agent. could you please help me in this?       Thanks!

Comment: This is no longer correct. See Kousha's answer below or visit this link: http://mms.mongodb.com/help-classic/tutorial/install-monitoring-agent-on-windows/ After installing the API key is the same key that you would find in the Mac OS X tutorial.

Comment: Actually, what was released was a monitoring agent - the automation agent has not yet been released (though it is planned) and that was what the question specifically asked about

Answer (score 3):

They have released a Windows Agent. You are able to simply install MongoDb MMS Windows Agent according to this official documentation:

http://mms.mongodb.com/help-classic/tutorial/install-monitoring-agent-on-windows/

Update: After installing the agent according to the above instructions, you need to submit a ticket in their support to enable monitoring for Windows. It can not be enabled automatically as it is not listed in their OS list yet.

Comment: Thanks this was an awesome find. However I was able to setup and configure my MMS monitoring on Windows without opening a ticket. The API key is the same key that you would find in the Mac OS X tutorial. I was able to connect it to mongoDB by adding a connection in the deployment tab.